# Java: How to verify that String has many characters

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

Consider the test messageTest(see below)

```
  publicclassmessageTest { 
    @Test
    publicvoidtestMessageLength() {
    String message = "Test Message";

    }
}
```

Add Assert method to verify that text in message contains 12 characters.

Comment: Please combine the knowledge behind these two links, one could easily found on the internet alone. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

Comment: Looks like homework!?

Answer (score 3):

You can assert it with actual length and expected length of the String. You need to import either junit [`Assert`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) or testNg [`Assert`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html), in order to use it

```
@Test
    publicvoidtestMessageLength() {
    String message = "Test Message";
    Assert.assertEquals(message.length(), 12);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29)

If that is what you are looking for.